# How to demonstrate RMSE for time series in percentages

Tags: time-series, error, model-evaluation

I am doing forecasting for a time-series problem, and have ended up with a RMSE of  3793.86.

I then took the mean of all the rows available to me, saw that it was 275007.975.

Is it correct to say that my RMSE percentage error is (3793.96 / 275007.975 * 100) = 1.38%? This is mainly for reporting purposes, as RMSE by itself doesn't seem intuitive to management, for example.

Or would a better metric to use be MAE ?

Answer (score 1):

"For presentation purposes, the Root Mean Squared Error was back-transformed (RMSEbt) by taking the anti-log of RMSE, subtracted by 1, and multiplied by 100. The resulting RMSEbt provided the percentage difference between observed and predicted values."

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-21285-1